# Generate a Vector of Identical Items of Length N

Tags: clojure

I would like to generate a vector of identical items given the item and a count. This seems like a something that should be easier to do than with a loop. Any ideas of making the function below tighter/streamlined?

```
;take an object and a nubmer n and return a vector of those objects that is n-long
(defn return_multiple_items [item number-of-items]
    (loop [x 0
           items [] ]
      (if (= x number-of-items)
           items
           (recur (+ x 1)
                  (conj items item)))))

>(return_multiple_items "A" 5 )
>["A" "A" "A" "A" "A"]
>(return_multiple_items {:years 3} 3)
>[{:years 3} {:years 3} {:years 3}]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a build-in function [repeat](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/repeat) designed especially for this case:

```
> (repeat 5 "A")
("A" "A" "A" "A" "A")
```

As you can see, it produce a sequence of identical elements. If you need a vector, you may conver it with [vec](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/vec):

```
> (vec (repeat 5 "A"))
["A" "A" "A" "A" "A"]
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I poked around on the clojure docs for a bit a couldn't find what I was looking for. THanks

Answer (score 1):

The `repeat` function come in handy here:

```
user> (defn return-multiple-items [item how-many] 
         (vec (repeat how-many item)))
#'user/return-multiple-items

user> (return-multiple-items "A" 5)
["A" "A" "A" "A" "A"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user> (into [] (repeat 5 "A"))
["A" "A" "A" "A" "A"]

user> (into [] (repeat 3 {:years 3}))
[{:years 3} {:years 3} {:years 3}]
```